# How to implement a trait on a Vec that can append a string?

Tags: rust, vector, traits

This is from trying Rustlings Exercise Traits2. The exercise requires me to implement the trait on a `Vec`. The tests are there and they are failing, which is a good place to start. I've done the trait implementation for the `String` and it was easy, but `Vec` is another story. I'm not sure what the method needs to return, it fails on various returns. I'm providing original code, my attempt and the errors i get for my attempt. Hopefully that will be enough.

Original Code from the Rustlings repo:

```rust
// traits2.rs
// 
// Your task is to implement the trait
// `AppendBar' for a vector of strings.
// 
// To implement this trait, consider for
// a moment what it means to 'append "Bar"'
// to a vector of strings.
// 
// No boiler plate code this time,
// you can do this!

// I AM NOT DONE

trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

//TODO: Add your code here




#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn is_vec_pop_eq_bar() {
        let mut foo = vec![String::from("Foo")].append_bar();
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Bar"));
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Foo"));
    }

}
```

and my attempt to solve it:

```rust
// traits2.rs
//
// Your task is to implement the trait
// `AppendBar' for a vector of strings.
//
// To implement this trait, consider for
// a moment what it means to 'append "Bar"'
// to a vector of strings.
//
// No boiler plate code this time,
// you can do this!

// I AM NOT DONE
use std::clone::Clone;
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self;
}

//TODO: Add your code here
impl<T: Clone> AppendBar for Vec<T> {
    fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self {
        let bar: T = String::from("Bar");
        self.to_vec().push(bar)
        // self.to_vec()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn is_vec_pop_eq_bar() {
        let mut foo = vec![String::from("Foo")].append_bar();
        assert_eq!(foo, vec![String::from("Foo"), String::from("Bar")]);
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Bar"));
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Foo"));
    }
}
```

Which compiles to an error:

```
! Compiling of exercises/traits/traits2.rs failed! Please try again. Here's the output:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/traits/traits2.rs:22:22
   |
20 | impl<T: Clone> AppendBar for Vec<T> {
   |      - this type parameter
21 |     fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self {
22 |         let bar: T = String::from("Bar");
   |                  -   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |                  |
   |                  expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                      found struct `std::string::String`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/traits/traits2.rs:23:9
   |
21 |     fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self {
   |                                 ---- expected `std::vec::Vec<T>` because of return type
22 |         let bar: T = String::from("Bar");
23 |         self.to_vec().push(bar)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found `()`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<T>`
           found unit type `()`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

I've read and re-read the suggested part and the traits in the book but it's beyond me. I'm sure it's a simple solution to it but i can't see it.

Comment: The task is not to implement the trait for Vec<T> (that seems impossible) but for Vec<String>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You try to push a `String` to generic `Vec<T>`, where `T` can be any type!
- The method signature is different from the assignment: Your method is defined as

  ```
  fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self
  ```

  but it should be

  ```
  fn append_bar(self) -> Self
  ```
- You try to return the result of `Vec::push`, but this method doesn't return anything.

To fix the first issue, implement the trait for `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<T>`. That's what the assignment is asking for:

> ```
> // Your task is to implement the trait
> // `AppendBar' for a vector of strings.
> ```

To fix the second issue, you have to remove the `&`, so the method accepts an *owned* value.

To fix the last issue, return `self` after calling `Vec::push` in a separate statement:

```
self.push(bar);
self
```

Comment: I have a serious question related to `mut self` signature in implementation. The trait signature says only `self` which is immutable, while the accepted solution implements the `mut self`. Even though this code will compile in rust, but don't you think that is creating a signature mismatch? Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @KaushalKishore When a value is moved, it doesn't matter for the method declaration whether or not it is mutated. An owned value can always be made mutable anyway: `let mut x = x;`

Comment: I was satisfying myself with the same hypothesis. Now it is confirmed. XD

Comment: In other words, when a value is owned, its mutability is not part of the type, only the _binding_. When calling a function or implementing a trait, only the types have to match, not the patterns of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

There's a discrepancy to Aloso's answer. Andre gives it too.

When you take in `self`:

```
fn append_bar(self) -> Self {
    self.push("Bar".to_owned());
    self
}
```

You are taking in a mutable `Vec`:

```
let mut foo = vec![String::from("Foo")].append_bar();
assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Bar"));
assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Foo"));
```

Even though the Variable `foo` is declared to be mutable, the method `append_bar()` takes in a immutable variable. You don't need to borrow `self` because you're not trying to take full ownership, you're trying to modify the existing data residing in said variable. The correct answer is

```
fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self {
    self.push("Bar".to_owned()); // || .to_string() || String::from("Bar") 
    // Whatever gets the point across. As the String literal is essentially a "Borrowed" string.
    self
}
```

Within the scope of `append_bar()` you're trying to mutate the collection of `String`s and return it with the appended string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct answer for this problem shall look like this:

```rust
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self {
        self.push("Bar".to_string());
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: crazy that we are allowed to have the impl take `mut self` while the trait only declares `self`

Comment: @xdavidliu I guess one could always make a mutable dummy variable and move `self` into that, i.e.`let mut foo = self;`to achieve the same result. Rust allowing the parameter to be `mut` directly is just a lot more convenient to write.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aloso for help and Jussi too i managed to get the example working.

Mutation was needed in order to compile, so i ended up with code that compiles as follows:

```rust
// traits2.rs
//
// Your task is to implement the trait
// `AppendBar' for a vector of strings.
//
// To implement this trait, consider for
// a moment what it means to 'append "Bar"'
// to a vector of strings.
//
// No boiler plate code this time,
// you can do this!

// I AM NOT DONE

trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self;
}

//TODO: Add your code here
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(&mut self) -> Self {
        self.push(String::from("Bar"));
        self.to_vec()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn is_vec_pop_eq_bar() {
        let mut foo = vec![String::from("Foo")].append_bar();
        assert_eq!(foo, vec![String::from("Foo"), String::from("Bar")]);
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Bar"));
        assert_eq!(foo.pop().unwrap(), String::from("Foo"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.to_vec()` looks weird: `self` is already a `Vec<String>`, right? So, `self` alone should suffice.

Comment: with self i get compile error like this https://gist.github.com/woss/5c43cec1780df884898703b4d7eb3188 but with `self.to_vec()` it goes away. not sure why

Comment: That's because you still have the wrong method declaration. According to the exercise, the method should accept `self` (an owned value) and not `&mut self` (a reference).

You can use `mut self`, which allows mutation and is compatible with `self` (since it's owned as well).

Comment: working fix => https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69ddcb49d0d8918fec0c4452b83c8c60